# Calling Assembly from C compile error gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-errors, gnu-assembler

Trying to run assembly in C, but won't compile with gcc

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "assem.s"
void extern testing(int * a);

int main(){
    int b = 8;
    int * a = &b;
    testing(a);
    printf("%d",*a);

}
```

assem.s

```
.globl testing

testing:
    ret
```

gcc

```
gcc main.c assem.s -o test.exe
```

error

```
expected identifier or '(' before '.' token .globl testing
```

Comment: You don't include `assem.s` as a `#include` in _C_. remove `#include "assem.s"`

Comment: `#include "assem.s"` statement inserts the contents of  assem.s into this C code.  Trying to compile `.globl testing` and obviously it is not a C code.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `#include "assem.s"` it takes the contents of the file `assem.s` and places it into the *C* at that point. The result would have the compiler trying to compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
.globl testing

testing:
    ret 

void extern testing(int * a);

int main(){
    int b = 8;
    int * a = &b;
    testing(a);
    printf("%d",*a);

}
```

Of course that's not what you want. The compiler attempted to compile the line `.globl testing` and it failed because it isn't proper *C* syntax and results in the error you got. All you have to do is remove `#include "assem.s"`.

`assem.s` will be assembled and then linked into the executable with the command `gcc main.c assem.s -o test.exe`. This one *GCC* command is the equivalent of the following except that intermediate object files won't be generated:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c assem.s -o assem.o
gcc main.o assem.o -o test.exe
```

You assemble/compile `.s` and `.S` files in the same fashion as `.c` files. `.s` and `.S` files should not be used with the *C* `#include` directive. There is a misconception among some new *GCC* users that they should be included and not assembled/linked separately.

Comment: Sheeze, now we have SO Nazis that downvote community wiki posts full of correct content -- go figure... Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You should change main.c like this. Then they could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "assem.s"
void extern testing(int * a);

int main(){
    int b = 8;
        int * a = &b;
    testing(a);
    printf("%d",*a);

    return 0;
}
```